Existence of probability measures $P$ such that for any $x\in \Omega$ and closed set $x\not\in A$, the inequality $ 0<P(A^c)$ holds.
Suppose $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space such that $\Omega$ is a topological space and $\Sigma$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.
For any such measurable spaces $(\Omega, \Sigma)$, does there exist probability measure $P$ such  that for any $x \in \Omega$ and closed set $A \subset \Omega$ not containing $x$ (i.e. $x \not\in A$), the inequality $0 < P(A^c)$ holds ?
Such probability measures obviously exist for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with a usual topology and Borel $\sigma$-algebra), but exist for more general measurable spaces ?
What if $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ is a infinite dimensional space or $\Omega$ has a large cardinality (e.g. $|\mathbb{R}| < |\Omega|$) ?
It seems to me that for such big (in some sense) measurable spaces, it is hard to find the probability measures $P$ because $P$ assigns probabilities to neighborhoods of every points evenly in a sense.
I would appreciate any help.

Edit
I realized that I should have state the required property for $P$ more concisely but equivalently like that for any $x\in \Omega$ and neighborhood $x\in U$, the inequality $P(U) > 0$ holds.
Anyway, the answer by @user6247850 completely solves my question.

OP is looking for a probability measure, not $A$

No, such a probability measure does not always exist.
Consider $\Omega = \ell^2([0,1])$, i.e. the space of functions on $[0,1]$ that are square integrable with respect to counting measure.  The topology is generated by open balls, and the $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Suppose working towards a contradiction that $P$ is a probability measure such that, for all $f\in \Omega$ and closed sets $A$ with $f \not \in A$ we have $P(A^c) > 0$.  For each $x \in [0,1]$, define the function $$f_x(y) := \begin{cases} 1 & x = y \\
0 & x \ne y. 
\end{cases}$$  For each $f_x$, we must have $B(f_x,\frac 12) = \{f \in \Omega : \|f-f_x\|_{\ell^2} < \frac 12\}$ has $P(B(f_x, \frac 12)) > 0$ because $B(f_x,\frac 12)^c$ is a closed set not containing $f_x$.  The sets $B(f_x, \frac 12)$ are all disjoint from one another, and are all open so $\bigcup_{x \in C} B(f_x,\frac 12)$ is open (and hence also measurable) for all countable subsets $C \subset [0,1]$.  However,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{C \subset [0,1],C \text{ countable}}P\left(\bigcup_{x \in C} B(f_x,\frac 12)\right) &= \sup_{C \subset [0,1],C \text{ countable}} \sum_{x \in C} P\left(B\left(f_x, \frac 12\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{x \in [0,1]} P\left(B\left(f_x, \frac 12\right)\right) \\
&= \infty
\end{align*}
because the sum of uncountably many non-zero values is infinite.  This contradicts that $P$ is a probability measure.

Thank you for the answer! If I understand your answer correctly, does it play essential role that $| \ell^2([0,1])| > |\mathbb{R}|$ holds and then you can take uncountably many neighborhoods all disjoint from one another in contrast to the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

@Krasiff The more important thing was being able to take uncountably many disjoint open sets.  There are topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ that allow this, too, I just find $\ell^2([0,1])$ to be convenient for generating counterexamples a lot of the time.

Thank you for your exposition!
